# Problems with stacking css in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Hey so I'm trying to stack CSS elements so they affect a element on after the other but the last one just plays instead of one after the other.

```
circleArray[i].css('-webkit-transform','rotate(180deg)').css('-webkit-transform','translateX(500px)');
```

I'm thinking I need to queue it

```
circleArray[i].queue(function(){
  $(this).css('-webkit-transform','rotate(180deg)');
  $(this).css('-webkit-transform','rotate(18deg)');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **css()** like this :

```
css({"propertyname":"value","propertyname":"value",...});

circleArray[i].css({"-webkit-transform":"rotate(180deg)","-webkit-transform":"rotate(18deg)"});
```